# Laguerre polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials

I tried using the .. command in MATLAB to generate Laguerre polynomials but I keep getting this error every time:

[image]

I found this in the help section:
[image]

Since I have defined **`x`** as symbolic I shouldn't be getting this error.

Also on website I  found this which says that the function does not run in MATLAB.[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Matlab are you running?  The Symbolic Toolbox documentation for [`laguerreL`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laguerrel.html#zmw57dd0e74197) says it was introduced in R2014b.

Comment: The warning is actually very clear.  You can only use `laguerreL` in the MuPAD Notebook Interface.  You are trying to run the command in a normal MATLAB setting.

Comment: so if i am trying to run this in normal matlab environment or including this in a script it wont run?

Comment: Your code works in 2015a, so it is probably a versions Problem. As for a solution... [FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4914-associatedlaguerrepoly-m) migth have something you could use instead :

Comment: @marcowassmer: That's because in R2014b+ `laguerreL` is a Symbolic Math function as well as a MuPAD function. The current documentation is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laguerrel.html).

Comment: @shrey: If you're using an old version of Matlab you need to be careful using Google to search for documentation. All of the online documentation is only meant to be valid for the current version of Matlab (R2015a at this time). You need to use the built-in documentation via `help` and `doc` or make sure you look at the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) for your version. `which laguerreL` will tell you that this function isn't directly available in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

Like you say, and the matlab help says this function only works inside mupad, maybe in later versions it works in matlab console.

If you want to use it, write mupad in Matlab Command window and then use it in the mupad, matlab will return you the result as I show in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In R2014b+, there is a [`laguerreL`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laguerrel.html) function available directly from within Matlab. However, a version of this function was introduced to [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html) in R2009a. You can call the MuPAD version from within Matlab

```
syms x;
feval(symengine,'laguerreL',2,x)
```

or

```
evalin(symengine,'laguerreL(2,x)')
```

Both return `x^2/2 - 2*x + 1`.

You can read more about interacting with MuPAD functionality from Matlab [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html). However, I'd recommend browsing and searching the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) for your specific `version` or using your built-in HTML documentation (e.g., `doc mupad` or `doc 'calling mupad'`).